# imagebutton not appearing on xml layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i am trying to make my page look like this : ( https://ibb.co/G22z2jq ) but it's looking like this :( https://ibb.co/pQ3fKhr ). the image of the button never appears ,

my code looks like this : https://gist.github.com/ApTreL/3f5400093e94f099f339c568ab6bcaaf

i have tried different resolutions and how do i know from the picture how much margin or padding do i need so it looks the exact same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" /><!--set scale type fit xy-->


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:src="@drawable/Lets-read-button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try and run the application?

Comment: yes i did , not working still

Answer (score 0):

try this code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" /><!--set scale type fit xy-->


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/Lets-read-button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply below code and you will get the expected result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="32dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_button"
            android:src="@drawable/Lets-read-button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

//  for button shape 
    rectangle_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" >
        <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/button_background_color" />
                </shape>
            </item>

        </ripple>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" >
        <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                </shape>
            </item>

        </ripple>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: i am a bit of noob , where do i write the second xml code ? the rectangle button one

Comment: drawable folder like where images situated

Comment: what specific folder in the drawable ?

Comment: create an xml file name it and paste the code. do it where your images are